# Determining a parameter value on a ElasticSearch template: search Template

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a ElasticSearch - search template that passes a field name to perform the sorting order. So if the parameter is name it orders by name, if parameter is date is ordered by age, if gender then it orders by gender.

I am trying to put all empty values (including empty "" strings) on the sort field at the end of the search at all times.

Fields are

```
 "name": {
    "type": "keyword",
  }
  "age": {
    "type": "byte"
  },
  "gender":{
    "type":"keyword"
  }
```

I have tried the following:

```
- missing: "_last"
- missing: "_first"
```

Neither work with keyword

- Painless scripting to boost non empty fields depending on type, unfortunately haven't manage to get this to work
- tried  matching by property type for boost , also was unable to make this work

  "template": {
      "from": "{{from}}",
      "size": "{{size}}",
      "sort": [
      "_score",
      {
      "{{sortField}}": {
      "order": "{{sortOrder}}"
      }
      }
      ],
      "query": {
      "bool": {
      "should":[
      {
      "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
      "bool": { 
      "must_not": [
      {
      "match": {
      "{{sortField1}}": ""
      }
      }
      ],
      "_name": "not empty string"
      }
      },
      "boost": 1000
      }
      }
      ],
      }
      }
      }

**expected result: (null is blank or empty space)**

Name|Age|Gender

James|31|Male

Jane|null|Female

Lizie|28|null|

Age order:

---

ASC:

Name|Age|Gender

Lizie|28|null|

James|31|Male

Jane|null|Female

---

DESC:

Name|Age|Gender

James|31|Male

Lizie|28|null|

Jane|null|Female

---

Gender order:

Asc:

Name|Age|Gender

Jane|null|Female

James|31|Male

Lizie|28|null|

---

Desc:
Name|Age|Gender

James|31|Male

Jane|null|Female

Lizie|28|null|

so my question is how can I know on the field value Name, Age or Gender  that is being passed with the value sortField. to manually match it to the correct boost rule?